# Django buildout on windows

Tags: django, buildout

For my django projects I have created a nice working workflow. Using buildout to 'bootstrap' a project and the apps I have developed based on versions. The rest are packages and apps installed from pypi. I work on ubuntu, and my servers are on ubuntu. This works like a charm.

Now there is a new developer who works on windows. He has a lot of troubles getting the buildout working the same way I Am using it.

Is there a special way or other way I should use buildout for setting it up for windows?

the usage of easy install seems to be the problem....

Windows user:
I have installed numpy and matplotlib with installers for windows(x64). But buildout still tries to compile matplotlib. The compilation is not working. I tried GCC as a compiler. Can I prevent buildout from compiling and using the installed packages?

Answer (score 1):

If something has a dependency on numpy or matplotlib, buildout will try to install it, period. So you have two basic solutions:

- Don't explicitly say you want numpy or matplotlib. Depend on it that you and your colleague already installed it globally. Buildout won't try to install what it doesn't know about :-)
- Use [syseggrecipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/syseggrecipe) to explicitly tell buildout to look for a package in your global install:

  ```
  [buildout]
  parts = 
      sysegg
      django
      ....

  [sysegg]
  recipe = syseggrecipe
  eggs =
      matplotlib
      numpy

  [django]
  recipe = djangorecipe
  ....
  ```

  Make sure the sysegg part is pretty much right at the start of your parts list. syseggrecipe places a link to your globally installed version in your buildout's `develop-eggs/` directory, thereby telling buildout about the package's existence.

  *Warning*: I'm not sure is syseggrecipe works 100% on windows, as it uses symlinks. Pull requests that fix it (if it turns out to be a problem) are welcome.

Comment: Buildout 2 also lets you use per-platform sections; you could keep a separate windows-only section. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.2.1#conditional-sections

Comment: Nice tips (both Reinout and Martijn), unfortunately... for this question.... the windows user decided to use ubuntu in vbox... so I cannot try/debug this problem with him anymore... I'll keep the question open (sorry) untill I have time to try all of above....